# Auto screen adjustment in <iframe> and scripts

Tags: php, html, css, iframe

How can I do auto screen adjustment in `<iframe>` and scripts? They contain link to external sites.

**`<iframe>` code**:

```
<iframe id="tmc-ticker" src="http://themoneyconverter.com/AUD/RateTicker.aspx" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" height="30px"  width="460px" style="float:left; margin:-1px 0px 0px 4px;"></iframe>
```

**Script**:

```
<script>
var width='460';
var profile='CMSForexWebQuotes1-B';
</script>
<script id="vtCurrencyPairs" src="http://webcharts.fxserver.com/pairs/js/addActivePairs.js">/**/</script>
<div> <a href="http://www.cmsfx.com"></a> </div>
```

Please take a look at the site: http://hannahsclinic.com/salaamforex/

On zoom in / zoom out the size changes.

Comment: Why not use width 100% for the iframes and use the parent width to determine the actual width ?

Comment: I have tried 100% but it doesnt make any change...How can i use parent width?

Comment: that is because your frame width is fixed to 460px. you need to change it to auto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `var width='460';` to var `width='100%';`. Same for iframe `width="100%"`

```
<script>
var width='100%';
var profile='CMSForexWebQuotes1-B';
</script>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yEwTy/1/)**

```
<div class="cmsfxWidgetWrapper" style="width: 460px; height: 346px;">
```

In the above code remove `width:460px` and make it `width:auto`